# The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http://localhost:3000, http://localhost:3000', but only one is allowed

Tags: reactjs, ubuntu, nginx, cors

So far none of the answers on SO was able to help me find a solution. I'm trying to access from localhost my API served on `Ubuntu` server with `Nginx`.
Here is how `Nginx` config looks like:
[image]

When I'm calling this from React app, I'm getting the error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.zapas.tech/manufacturers' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http://localhost:3000, http://localhost:3000', but only one is allowed.

While the same request from Postman working well. I'm pretty sure that nothing CORS related made in React app.

Answer (score 2):

Is your request method options? If so, you are adding headers twice.

You're adding:
1,2,3

And if 'if' condition is true you also add:
1,2,3,additional data.

So if the condition is true, your data looks like:1,2,3,1,2,3, additional data

Just delete duplicates in your if loop and it'll probably work:)

Comment: I concur with this answer. The existing code in the question causes two Access-Control-Allow-Origin response headers to be sent back. When the browser receives those, it joins their values with a comma and then evaluates that combined value. So the existing nginx config code in the question needs to be changed to prevent it from sending multiple Access-Control-Allow-Origin response headers the way it is now.

Comment: Further, as far as Access-Control-Allow-Headers and Access-Control-Allow-Methods headers, the server only needs to send those in response to the OPTIONS request. The response to the OPTIONS request is the only case when the browser checks those headers. They don’t need to be sent in response to a GET or POST or whatever else. So they can be removed from the first part of the nginx config code in the question, but kept just in the part that handles responding to the OPTIONS request.